# Pass posts_per_page to Timber's TimberTerm() on taxonomy archive page

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

On a custom taxonomy archive (taxonomy-strategy.php), I would like to display all custom posts that have a taxonomy called strategy.

As per the TimberTerm [documentation](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-term/), I am using `$context['term_page'] = new TimberTerm();` and then, in `taxonomy-strategy.twig`:

`{% for post in term_page.posts %}
  {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}`

The problem is that only 10 of the posts with that taxonomy are being outputted. I have changed my reading settings to +25 posts. I have tried passing `TimberTerm()` parameters to to unrestrict the number of posts, but unlike `get_terms` or other similar functions, `TimberTerm()` does not accept such a parameter.

I would prefer to solve this issue on the taxonomy archive page, since the user gets here by following the term name.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved through directly through the view:

`{% for post in term_page.posts('numberposts_or_args=-1') %}
    {{ post.etcetc }}
{% endfor %}`

where `term_page` is defined by `$context['term_page'] = new TimberTerm();`, making the term in question defined by the template hierarchy: `taxonomy-[taxname].php`